# .pycharm_helpers/packaging_tool.py: Permission denied

Tags: pycharm, remote-debugging

My pycharm version is pycharm2020.1.1, and I use ssh to log in remote server. But there was an warning `Couldn't upload helpers for remote interpreter: File:/Library/Caches/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.1/remote_sources/858584654/-733841145/.pycharm_helpers/packaging_tool.py: Permission denied` . I check the permissions of .pycharm_helpers and its subfile in local and remote server. The permission of all the file and directory are `rwxrwxrwx`. I don't know why it still don't have permission. And when I click a function, it will redirect to the file in `/Library/Caches/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.1/remote_sources/`, not in my project.

Answer (score 2):

I have this exact same issue. A temporary solution is to delete then reconfigure the ssh connection.

Something I've tried this morning that *seems* to be working so far is to move the `~/.pycharm_helpers` folder to the local project root (`/usr/PycharmProjects/<your_proj>`) and to the remote project root, then configure a mapping between the two in `Deployment|Mappings`. This looks like it might provide a longer-term solution.

Also, change all read/write accessibility to 777.

Comment: I use another temporary solution too. I change the `Project Interpreter` to my local interpreter first, and then change it to remote interpreter. It will auto refresh the cache.